# MessageBox with timeout in Selenium

Tags: java, javascript, browser, selenium

After writing some automated tests with selenium, I want a message box 
telling the testers which test is launched.

It is important, that the test must not run when the messagebox is shown.
They should be paused when the messagebox is shown.

I did this by JavaScript

```
Object result = ((JavascriptExecutor)TestRunner.driver).executeScript("alert('" + text + "');");
```

Now I want this messagebox to be shown some seconds. I tried:

```
TestRunner.driver.manage().wait(10);
```

And

```
Selenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(TestRunner.driver,    TestRunner.driver.getCurrentUrl());
selenium.start();
selenium.getConfirmation();
```

And

```
WebDriverWait waitForOkay = new WebDriverWait(TestRunner.driver, 10);
waitForOkay.wait(10);
```

But the alert always immediately disapears, just like there is some

```
alert.accept();
```

Is there any way to have a messagebox that is either clicked "Ok" or
some timeout (e.g. 10 seconds) to not block automated tests?

Any input (like other ways to achieve that) very welcome!

Comment: Why do you want a message box for this? The whole idea is to have your suite totally automated, you are requiring human intervention (to click 'OK' to the alert), so how do you propose to run the tests when nobody is around to click OK? If you are telling your testers what tests are being run, use a log file.

Comment: I want a message box because the PO said he wants to see what is going on. He even wants to let the test run and write the results up. Sure, selenium is about automated testing, but it should be possible to have user interaction if wanted. It seems to work quite well, except that the tests run on in the background. Probably there are better ways for that, just make a suggestion. What to do if the PO wants the start of each test manually, but the testing as a whole only once?

Answer (score 0):

A wait condition is unnecessary in this situation, since by Default the JavaScript alert box.... blocks the execution till you click on "Ok" button.

I tried with sample code (C# snippet) and it was working.

```
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));
Console.WriteLine("Entering the Sync Call");
js.ExecuteScript("alert('"+ Error+"');");
Console.WriteLine("Exiting the Sync Call");
```

I hope this helps...All the Best :-)

Comment: In my example this does not seem to be a Sync call using firefox. The alert pops up for about 0.2 seconds and then is "accepted" magically. I want it to be readable for a human, i.e. be shown for about 10 seconds and then time out.

Comment: lemme try the same with FF

Comment: It is not working for me, because the tests run on in the background. Seems like the javascript is executed in another thread.